# How can I detect how yellow an image is

Tags: java, android

I want to ignore all other colours. I just want to count the colours between white and yellow(Bright yellow, Light yellow.. all the way to white). and then give a rating of how yellow a certain image is. is that possible?

I have been playing with `Bitmap.getPixel()` but I can't figure out how to ignore other colours.

[image]

In this example, image 1 would be the one select because it has more colour between bright yellow and white.

How can I detect yellowish colours only?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well I would focus on the HUE of the pixel.  Using this code:

```
// get HSV values for the pixel's colour
float[] pixelColorHsv = new float[3];
Color.colorToHSV(Bitmap.getPixel(x,y), pixelColorHsv);
```

What is Yellow might be up to you but a range could be between 72 and 49 (you can play with [this tool](http://www.colblindor.com/color-name-hue/) to get an idea) then you can quantify where it is in this range or how high or low the brightness and saturation are.

Answer (score 1):

The `Bitmap.getPixel(int x, int y)` method returns a `Color` object with the RGB values for that pixel. Yellow is a combination of red and green, so a straight yellow RGB triple would be (255, 255, 0), right? If you get darker, you lower both of the red and green values. If you get brighter, you bring up the blue value. So basically, you need to find a way to detect how "close" any given pixel's RGB value comes to (255, 255, 0) and then accumulate those closeness values for the entire image. Do the same for the second image, then compare the 2 results.

Comment: On second thought, Jason's method is probably much easier to implement. Use `getPixel` to get the `Color` object, then use `Color.colorToHSV` to convert to HSV and compare the H (hue) to a range you deem to be a valid range for yellow.